# Cannot mount vmfs version 5 on linux

Tags: linux, mount, esxi

I know I can mount a vmfs version 3 on linux using vmfs-tools.

First I get the iscsi connection using open-iscsi

I then check in my partition tool to which virtual drive the iscsi connection has been mapped.

```
  Expert Partitioner                                                       

   ┌System View────────────────────────┐Available Storage on serviceseta
   │─┬─serviceseta                     │┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │ ├+─Hard Disks                     ││Device   │     Size│F│Enc│Type               │FS Type│Label│Mount Point               │
   │ ├──RAID                           ││/dev/sda │  2.00 TB│ │   │VMware-Virtual disk│       │     │                          │
   │ ├──Volume Management              ││/dev/sda1│195.00 MB│ │   │Linux native       │Ext4   │     │/boot                     │
   │ ├──Crypt Files                    ││/dev/sda2│  4.00 GB│ │   │Linux swap         │Swap   │     │swap                      │
   │ ├──Device Mapper                  ││/dev/sda3│  2.00 TB│ │   │Linux native       │Ext4   │     │/                         │
   │ ├──NFS                            ││/dev/sdb │  1.56 TB│ │   │IET-VIRTUAL-DISK   │       │     │                          │
   │ ├──BTRFS                          ││/dev/sdb1│  1.56 TB│ │   │unknown            │       │     │                          │
   │ ├──TMPFS                          ││/dev/sdd │  7.52 TB│ │   │IET-VIRTUAL-DISK   │       │     │                          │
   │ └──Unused Devices                 ││/dev/sdd1│  7.52 TB│ │   │Linux native       │       │     │                          │
   │───Installation Summary            ││tmpfs    │498.27 MB│ │   │TMPFS              │TmpFS  │     │/dev/shm                  │
```

OK I can see there's two IET virtual disks and I can tell which is which from the size.
So I know I need to mount `/dev/sbd1` and `/dev/sdd1` somehow.

One of these disks (extends actually) is VMFS3, the other is VMFS5.

I can mount the VMFS3 using

```
vmfs-fuse /dev/sdb1 /mnt/opensuse1600gb
```

However if I try the same using the big storage

```
vmfs-fuse /dev/sdd1 /mnt/opensuse7700gb
```

I get

> Error stat()ing '/dev/ssd1'

If I then try

```
debugvmfs /dev/sdd1 df
```

I get

> VMFS: Unsupported version 5
>   Unable to open device/file "/dev/sdd1".

**Is there some tool that supports mounting vmfs5?**

Answer (score 1):

There are some limitations using vmfs-tools. If you have VMFS6 or VMFS5 with files bigger than 256GB you should use a Virtual Machine (or a lab machine) to access the files:

1. Download ESXi ISO file from https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=free-esxi6 (60 days trial and limited free version)
2. Create a new VM at VMWare Workstation and install ESXi
3. Attach the VMFS disk to the VM as a physical disk (also you can create a vmdk file pointing to a disk image)
4. Open vSphere Web Client with a web browser on the host machine, accessing the IP address shown at the VM screen
5. The datastore should be visible at Storages -> Datastores, if not you can try the workaround available at https://www.hex64.net/vmware-esxi-can-not-add-existing-iscsi-lun/
6. Click at Datastore browser, choose the file you want and click at download button

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the version of **vmfs-tools** package by running the following command:

```
dpkg-query -l vmfs-tools
```

According to the following [article](http://glandium.org/blog/?p=2194) the **VMFS5** is supported prior to **0.2.5** version only.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to follow the instructions to get the right tools from [here](http://tkurek.blogspot.nl/2013/05/vmfs-unsupported-version-5-how-to-mount.html).

then:

```
root@it:/home/it/mnt/vmfs# /usr/local/sbin/vmfs-fuse /dev/cciss/c0d0p3 ./vmfs
```

Comment: While citing a link as a source is fine, pointing to the link as the answer is generally discouraged. Please provide linked information in the answer to help fight link rot.